# get entities for last 7 days in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i need to fetch entities for the last 7 days, and if fewer than 50 entities are fetched extend the range to 10 days, the model is something like:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    plays = db.IntegerProperty()
```

I also need to order by number of plays descending.

any help is appreciated
thanks
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test the code right now but I would do something like :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

query = MyModel.gql("WHERE date > :1 ORDER BY plays DESC", datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7))
count = query.count()
if count < 50:
   query = MyModel.gql("WHERE date > :1", datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10))
value = query.fetch()
```

Comment: hmm i can seem to order the query as you can only order by the value specified in the inequality filter, which is date not plays.

is it possible to order the result (list) after the query? so fetch the entities for the date range then order the list by plays afterwards?

Comment: I got it working, just used the query above without the ordering, and then ordered the returned query list with sorted()